# State doesn't change in Flutter app using BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm building an app which fetches hotel names from an API. I'm using the BLoC library. I managed to create whole service which downloads the data, but the result doesn't show in my terminal.

My BLoC works, it downloads the data. I saw it in Dart DevTools, but the state doesn't change and it does not show up.

Here's my code:

### hotel_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:hotels/controllers/hotel/hotel_controller.dart';
import 'package:hotels/models/hotel/hotel_model.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'hotel_event.dart';
part 'hotel_state.dart';

class HotelBloc extends Bloc<HotelEvent, HotelState> {
  HotelBloc() : super(HotelLoading());

  final HotelController hotelController = HotelController();

  @override
  Stream<HotelState> mapEventToState(
    HotelEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchEvent) {
      yield HotelLoading();

      try {
        final Hotels hotels = await hotelController.parseHotels();

        yield HotelFinal(hotels);
      } catch (error) {
        HotelError(error);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### hotel_state.dart

```
part of 'hotel_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HotelState {
  HotelState();
}

class HotelFinal extends HotelState {
  final Hotels hotels;

  HotelFinal(this.hotels);

  Hotels getHotel() {
    return hotels;
  }
}

class HotelLoading extends HotelState {
  HotelLoading();
}

class HotelError extends HotelState {
  final String error;

  HotelError(this.error);
}
```

### hotel_event.dart

```
part of 'hotel_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class HotelEvent {
  HotelEvent();
}

class FetchEvent extends HotelEvent {
  FetchEvent();
}
```

### hotel_service.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

abstract class DownloadService {
  Future<http.Response> fetchHotels();
}

class HotelService extends DownloadService {
  @override
  Future<http.Response> fetchHotels() {
    final Uri uri = Uri.https('services.lastminute.com', 'mobile/stubs/hotels');

    return http.get(uri);
  }
}
```

### hotel_controller.dart

```
import 'package:hotels/models/hotel/hotel_model.dart';
import 'package:hotels/services/hotel/hotel_service.dart';

class HotelController {
  final HotelService hotelService = HotelService();

  Future<Hotels> parseHotels() async {
    final response = await hotelService.fetchHotels();

    final hotels = hotelsFromJson(response.body);

    return hotels;
  }
}
```

And finally the HomeScreen

### home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:hotels/blocs/hotel/hotel_bloc.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  HotelBloc hotelBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    hotelBloc = HotelBloc()..add(FetchEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    hotelBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title').tr(),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<HotelBloc, HotelState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is HotelError) {
            print(state.error);
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is HotelLoading) {
            print('It\'s loading!');
          }

          if (state is HotelFinal) {
            print(state.hotels.toString());
          }

          return Text('Default text');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result is this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the you haven't provided the `BlocConsumer` with your `hotelBloc`. You want to either have `BlocProvider` as a parent or use the `cubit` parameter on `BlocConsumer`.

```dart
BlocConsumer<HotelBloc, HotelState>(
  cubit: hotelBloc,
  listener:...
  builder:...
)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, BlocProvider is above all widgets. I think it works, but the state doesn’t change. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, do you have a git repository with this code? I'd like to take a look if you'd like

Comment: I don’t, I mean yeah I have, but it’s private. I don’t want to make it public since it’s a private project.

Comment: I'll give you a chat, you could add me as a contributor for a little while

Comment: Sure, send me a message then I will add you.

Comment: Okay i can't find the message ability on stackoverflow. My github name is stijnie2210 if you can add by username

Comment: give me 15 minutes. I will add you once I’m back on my computer.

Comment: Added you to the repo. Can you check the code?

Comment: I fixed it, I created a pull request for you :)

Comment: Dude! It works like a charm! Thanks a lot! You made my day :)

Comment: You're welcome! if you ever need any other help just hmu